# How to use awesome_print for Ruby file that makes a HTTP request

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
require 'net/https'

uri = URI('https://api.clever.com/v1.1/sections')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.add_field 'Authorization', 'Bearer DEMO_TOKEN'

response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

The problem is that my code output is gross and hard to read in terminal. I'm trying to clean it up with awesome print but it isn't working... this is what I'm trying:

```
require 'net/https'
require 'awesome_print'

uri = URI('https://api.clever.com/v1.1/sections')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.add_field 'Authorization', 'Bearer DEMO_TOKEN'

response = http.request(request)
ap response.body
```

but it's not formatting at all the way I need it to. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse your `response.body` to JSON and use `pretty_generate()` function, built into later versions of JSON.

```
require 'net/https'
require 'json'

uri = URI('https://api.clever.com/v1.1/sections')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.add_field 'Authorization', 'Bearer DEMO_TOKEN'

response = http.request(request)
myjson = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts JSON.pretty_generate(myjson)
```

Which will give you output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "course_name": "Fine Arts, Class 703",
    "course_number": "703",
    "created": "2014-02-26T21:15:38.324Z",
    "district": "4fd43cc56d11340000000005",
    "grade": "7",
    "last_modified": "2015-09-30T21:08:09.877Z",
    "name": "Fine Arts, Class 703 - 703 - A. Ortiz (Section 3)",
    "period": "7",
    "school": "530e595026403103360ff9ff",
    "sis_id": "674",
    "students": [
      "530e5960049e75a9262cff59",
      "530e5960049e75a9262cff99",
      "530e5961049e75a9262cffd5",
      "530e5961049e75a9262d001c",
      "530e5961049e75a9262d008a",
      "530e5962049e75a9262d0144",
      "530e5962049e75a9262d0155",
      "530e5962049e75a9262d015e",
      "530e5963049e75a9262d0200",
      "530e5963049e75a9262d022d",
      "530e5963049e75a9262d023a",
      "530e5964049e75a9262d0275",
      "530e5964049e75a9262d029b",
      "530e5964049e75a9262d02c0",
      "530e5964049e75a9262d02de",
      "530e5965049e75a9262d034a",
      "530e5965049e75a9262d0354",
      "530e5965049e75a9262d03c7",
      "530e5966049e75a9262d0419",
      "530e5966049e75a9262d046d",
      "530e5966049e75a9262d0489",
      "530e5967049e75a9262d0560",
      "530e5967049e75a9262d05b4",
      "530e5967049e75a9262d05bb",
      "530e5968049e75a9262d0621",
      "530e5968049e75a9262d0637"
    ],
    "subject": "arts and music",
    "teacher": "530e5955d50c310f36112bec",
....
.... 
# I have not post full output but it's pretty good and well structured
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to print the `Hash`, not the raw `String`. So use `JSON.parse(response.body)` would solve your problem.

---

Alternatively, use `pp` and `json`, they are all from stdlib.

```
require 'net/https'
require 'pp'
require 'json'

uri = URI('https://api.clever.com/v1.1/sections')
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  request["authorization"] = "Bearer DEMO_TOKEN"
  http.request(request) do |response|
    pp JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

---

But ultimately, I would recommend to use `pry` for debugging. It just make life easier 10x for debuging.

```
gem install pry
```

Then change above code to:

```
require 'net/https'
require 'pry'
require 'json'

uri = URI('https://api.clever.com/v1.1/sections')
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  request["authorization"] = "Bearer DEMO_TOKEN"
  http.request(request) do |response|
    res = JSON.parse(response.body)
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

After running the file in your terminal, it will paused at where you put `binding.pry`. Then type `res`, you will see the nicely formatted hash.

Have fun with `pry`!

Answer (score 1):

`awesome print` is print your Ruby data structures (Hash, Array etc.) in an easy to read format. Not for HTML!

If you want to format HTML in an easy to read manner, take a look at Nokogiri. Example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

# your response html
html = response.body

doc = Nokogiri::XML(html,&:noblanks)
puts doc.to_xhtml(indent:4)
```